# PHP DomXpath xpath query of Child Node

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath, child-nodes

I'm trying to use xpath to query some HTML:

```
<a target="_blank" class="dx-smart-widget-grid-item_113_20" href="https://link.com" title="Rules for the Road to One Source of Truth' with Jaguar Land Rover and Spark44">
            <div class="dx-smart-widget-grid-info_113_20">
                <img class="dx-smart-widget-report-cover_113_20" src="https://imagelink.com/preview.png" alt="The Alternative Text"/>
                <div class="dx-smart-widget-grid-text_113_20">
                    <div class="dx-smart-widget-grid-title_113_20">The Alternative Text</div>
                </div>
                <span class="dx-smart-widget-report-assettype_113_20">On-Demand Webinar</span>
                <img class="dx-smart-widget-partner-logo_113_20" src="https://logopath/logo.png" alt="censhare"/>
            </div>
        </a>
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
@ $dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$elements = $xpath->query("//a[contains(@class,'dx-smart-widget-grid-item_113_20')]");

if (!is_null($elements)) {
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
      echo "<strong>Link: </strong>". $element->getAttribute('href'). "<br />";
      echo "<strong>Title: </strong>". $element->getAttribute('title'). "<br />";

      $images = $xpath->query("//img[contains(@class,'dx-smart-widget-report-cover_113_20')]", $element);
      echo "<strong>Image: </strong>".$images->getAttribute('src'). "<br />";
    }
  }
```

I'm gettin the href and title fine... but trying to query the image just isn't working. It actually breaks.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is only 1 matching image, you can use XPaths `evaluate()` and `string()` in the XPath expression to extract the value in one go...

```
$images = $xpath->evaluate("string(//img[contains(@class,'dx-smart-widget-report-cover_113_20')]/@src)", $element);
echo "<strong>Image: </strong>".$images. "<br />";
```

Comment: How do I get it to return the src attribute? I tried $images->getAttribute('src') but that didn't return it.

Comment: @douglaskarr, added `/@src` to the XPath

Comment: Boom! That did it... boy can this get confusing. I tried to vote it up but I'm too much of a newb here.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. You just need to iterate over `$images` in a `foreach` loop. So replace

```
echo "<strong>Image: </strong>".$images->getAttribute('src'). "<br />";
```

with

```
foreach ($images as $image) {
     echo "<strong>Image: </strong>".$image->getAttribute('src'). "<br /and i>";
};
```

and it should work.

Comment: It looks like that's going through the entire HTML dom object and not just within that one anchor content. Is there any way to constrain it within the specific element?

Comment: @douglaskarr It shouldn't it should only go through the child nodes of `$elements`. That's the function of the context parameter`, $element` at the end of `$images = $xpath->evaluate("string(//img[contains(@class,'dx-smart-widget-report-cover_113_20')]/@src)", $element);`.

Comment: Yea, it's bizarre... could be that my initial query need updated. @nigel-ren's solution worked, though!